# web audio api oscillator won't play in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, audio

I'm using firefox 44.0 on Ubuntu 15.04 and for some reason text I can't get an oscillator to play a sound.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Web Audio API</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <h1>Welcome to the Web Audio API</h1>
    <script>
      // create the audio context

      var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkit.AudioContext)();

      var osc = audioCtx.createOscillator();
      osc.connect(audioCtx.destination);
      osc.type = 'sine';
      osc.frequency.value = 250;
      osc.start(0);
      osc.stop(1);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This works under a chromium browser as expexted but no sound is played on firefox.  Is this a problem with firefox or with linux?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: seems to work in firefox for windows

Comment: I was afraid that it was a linux problem thank you for your help

Comment: icewesel (version 38 in debian jessie) works - so, firefox should